# Selecting sample from a list of n numbers without repeating

Tags: python, list, random, combinations, sampling

So lets say I have a python list:

```py
num_list = ["3", "2", "5", "6", "9", "3", "0"]
```

What I want to do is:
each time select a sample with 5 numbers from this list;
the first number can only be 0, 3, or 9.

How can I write an algorithm in python find all the combinations that can be sampled from the list with the above two conditions?

I have used the random module in python, but it can't do restricted sample selection like the condition for first number being only 0, 3 or 9.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please add the expected output for the example you added? i.e., what are the expected combinations for this example.

Comment: For example, is this a valid result `[3,3,2,5,6]`? You have `3` twice in your source list, so would it be considered repeated or not?

Comment: Yes, it won't be considered repeated. not repeated i mean only the sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to sample from all the combinations (which would quickly  become prohibitive as you increase the number of items).  Instead, separate the selection of the first item from sampling of the rest.  To do so, select the first number from a random choice of the indexes that contain 0, 3 or 9.  Then pick a sample of 4 from the remaining positions

```
nums = ["3", "2", "5", "6", "9", "3", "0"]

import random

firstIndexes = [i for i,n in enumerate(nums) if n in "039"]
for _ in range(10):
   i0 = random.choice(firstIndexes)
   result = (nums[i0],*random.sample(nums[:i0]+nums[i0+1:],4))
   print(result)

('9', '2', '0', '6', '5')
('3', '0', '6', '2', '9')
('9', '5', '3', '3', '2')
('3', '0', '9', '3', '5')
('9', '0', '2', '3', '6')
('3', '6', '5', '2', '3')
('0', '9', '3', '3', '6')
('3', '2', '3', '9', '6')
('9', '3', '6', '2', '3')
('9', '5', '0', '2', '3')
```

Comment: How does this answer resolves the "find all the combinations that can be sampled" part of the problem?

Comment: The OP was looking for a sample (hence the random approach). I took the "find all the combinations" statement as a means to an end, not the objective per se.

Comment: Which seems to be the correct assumption, provided that he accepted the answer. If you can add a suggestion on the "findall" problem, this answer could be more useful even for future people that ends up here.

Comment: Good point. I amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

create a for loop with elements = `['0', '3', '9']`
then make a variable x = [element]
then use random.choice as usual

```
    num_list = ['3','2','5','6','9','3','0']
    combinations = []
    elements = ['0', '3', '9']
    for element in elements:
        x = [element]
        while len(x) < 5:
            x.append(random.choice(num_list))
        else:
            combinations.append(x)
        # you need to make the part under for loop run till all combinations
        # are stored
        # you also need to remove the current element from the list or else
        # it will be considered twice, to do this make a copy of list and 
        # remove the current element in the for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

If your assignment is to come up with the algorithm by yourself completely, you could iterate over the permutations and filter on every iteration by the condition of the first element being in the checklist.

If your assignment accepts using built-in modules, I recommend you to take a look at the python `itertools`. In your case, the `permutations` function.

```
from itertools import permutations

num_list = ['3','2','5','6','9','3','0']
# permutations(num_list, 5) is the important here, where 5 is the size of the sample
result = list(filter(lambda n: n[0] in ('0','3','9'), permutations(num_list, 5)))

print(len(result)) #1440

print(*result[:6], sep='\n') # listing only the first 6 results
# ('3', '2', '5', '6', '9')
# ('3', '2', '5', '6', '3')
# ('3', '2', '5', '6', '0')
# ('3', '2', '5', '9', '6')
# ('3', '2', '5', '9', '3')
# ('3', '2', '5', '9', '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear if you want all possible arrangements of that list of or truly all permutations from a random selection. That is, can you sample the same number from the list twice or are the numbers essentially being popped of the list at selection time.

Let's assume you need every [combination](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) of length 5 where 0, 3, or 9 begin the list.

```py
from itertools import combinations

num_list = ["3", "2", "5", "6", "9", "3", "0"]

c = combinations(num_list, 5)
candidates = [l for l in c if l[0] in ["0", "3", "9"]]
```

This yields a list of `candidates` that is 15 items long.

If instead you want all possible length 5 [permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) of that list.

```py
from itertools import permutations

num_list = ["3", "2", "5", "6", "9", "3", "0"]

p = permutations(num_list, 5)
candidates = [l for l in p if l[0] in ["0", "3", "9"]]
```

That yields a list of `canbidates` that is 1440 items long as it allows for repeated elements.

---

So these allow you to find all possible, if you *need* to find all possible. But if you need to do so randomly without finding all possible, no sense wasting the memory and time on list, just pull them from the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) objects directly as they are [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) that will [yield](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) as required.

Comment: Yeah, OP should clarify if he means combinations or permutations

Answer (score -2):

One way would be to use a simple loop to iterate until you get one of the selected numbers:

```
number = None
while True:
    number = random.choice(arr)
    if number in [0, 3, 9]:
        break
```

Then use the `random.choice` as usual for the rest of the numbers.

Comment: You know this could run forever without terminating, right?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Whatever problems this answer has, that isn't one of them. The number of iterations has a geometric distribution with p=3/7, so the expected run time is 7/3 iterations, i.e., less than 3. It runs forever with probability zero.

Comment: I am not saying it will, we both know it won't, because the cardinality of the permutations with r=5 is about 2k. The point is: iteration over random choice is not the right approach.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues It is the start of a valid approach, because it is mathematically correct - acceptance/rejection schemes are well-known and widely accepted in many contexts. If you want to point out that there are computationally more efficient choices, that's fair (but you should give one), but your initial response is false.

Comment: @pjs, OP's question is to "find all the combinations". If OP puts this in a loop and store any unseen value, what is the average number of iterations until he lists them all?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues irrelevant to your initial comment. My friendly advice is that you delete it, and we all move on.

Comment: @pjs, no can do. If `random.choice` has a vicious seed that delivers '5' as initial value on every combination, it will run forever.

Comment: To quote you yourself, "we both know it won't". You've said something incorrect, now you're trying to rationalize it. Deleting it is the better choice.

Comment: Last comment on the subject: the problem is not that it will run forever - it won't. The problem is that it could - because it is fundamentally wrong to try and exhaust the combinations of a list by randomly picking from them, without reducing the domain. I couldn't care less if the probability tends to 0 on infinity time, or whatever. This is not a math forum, this is a coding forum. If I ever do a code review with such snippet, I'd reject the commit, as would any sensible engineer. Comment will remain there, as it could make both OP and responder to learn something new and relevant.